# Is it possible to Use HTML5 AppCache in an Angular 4 Project?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, html5-appcache

I have been trying to use AppCache in my Angular CLI project, and have been following all AppCache guides which seem pretty straight forward, but I keep getting this error:

[image]

My manifest.appcache file is in the same directory as my index.html.

**manifest.appcache:**

[image]

I have also tried referencing the manifest.appcache file through an iframe tag, but i also get an error by doing that saying that the it cannot find that iframe-inject-appcache-manifest.html file either. I'm am not sure if it is possible to implement AppCache on angular 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that your browser receives a 404 seems to point to a web server configuration problem more than an Angular specific issue.

You may want to dig in for angular cli's server configuration or (if it is not exposed) go for a standard alternative (Apache/nginx/express...)

Also note that the manifest is supposed to be served by your web server with the mime type: text/cache-manifest, though [this article](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/) says it is not mandatory anymore.

Answer (score 0):

please add  manifest.appcache in angular cli json under the assets directory , after that it will be included in final build.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it in angular application.

As Dinesh Shah said: please add manifest.appcache in angular json under the assets directory , after that it will be included in final build.

And your manifest.appcahce should look like this.

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# v1.0.1
/index.html
/polyfills.js
/main.js
/styles.js
/runtime.js
/vendor.js
/favicon.ico
NETWORK:
*
```